# Performance of a semi transparent Window over multiple screens when moving a rectangle in realtime

Tags: wpf, performance, drawing, screen

I've a small app which show a semi transparent window over the whole desktop. The window isn't shown in the taskbar and has not titlebar

On this window the user can drag a rectangle with the mouse.
When the mouse button is released, a screenshot of the given area is taken. (Something like the snipping tool in windows 7)

In order to achieve this, the window contains a RectangleGeometry.

Now in the CompositionTarget.Rendering event the rectangle where set to the location where the mouse was when the mouse down occured, also it is sized to cover the area to the current mouse position.

This works really fine as long as only one monitor is connected.
When a second monitor with a higher resolution is connected the performance decreases dramatically.

The resolution of the laptop display is  1600x1200

The display which is connected has 1900x1200

Also when connecting the display it changed the primary screen to the new one

Heres the window definition

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" WindowStyle="None" >

the geometry definition
<Path Fill="Black" Opacity="0.4" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3">
   <Path.Data>
       <RectangleGeometry  x:Name="Inner" Rect="105,5,90,90"/>
   </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Here a portion of the code which moves the rectangle

```
System.Windows.Rect location = new System.Windows.Rect(this.DragStart.X, this.DragStart.Y, width, height);
```

this.Inner.Rect = rect;

Does anyone have an idea on how to improve the performance ?
Is it "normal" that the performance decreases so much on higher resolutions with multiple displays ?

Comment: I found out that the performance increases when the window is getting smaller. Seems like it is more related on the size then the secondary screen. does anyone know wether large screens are a problem for WPF ?

Answer (score 2):

First off, I'm not sure that the CompositionTarget.Rendering is the right tool for the job - it might be causing more damage than good - try using a simple rectange within a canvas...

We commonly have a main application window spanning 3-4 1920x1200 screens. There is a noticable (but tolerable) performance drop when using multiple screens compared to one screen.

We found that using win XP span mode or win7 NVIDIA mosaic mode helped greatly reduce performance drop (we have full control over the runtime environment).

Note that we had to disable AllowsTransparency for the main window - when this option was enabled the performance drop was not tolerable!

Also try forcing software rendering - it might suprise you (and in my experience it is the only way to ensure stable and artifact free multiscreen WPF environment in win XP, especially combined with any NVIDIA quadro graphic card).